# create a set get class and pass parameter in constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net & trying create a object, but there is a syntax error

```
public class pair
{

    private string key;
    private string value;

    public pair(string key, string value)
    {
        this.key = this.setKey(key);
        this.value = this.setValue(value);
    }

    private void setKey (string key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public string getKey()
    {
        return this.key;
    }

    private void setValue(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public string getValue()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

these two lines

```
this.key = this.setKey(key);
this.value = this.setValue(value);
```

have something wrong, anyone know the problems?

Comment: Why you asked then..?@hkinterview

Comment: You're assigning return value of a method which does not have a return value (void). You should pay more attention to the compiler's error messages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need two properties here or just use

```
public class Pair
{
    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public Pair(string key, string value)
    {
        this.Key= key;
        this.Value = value;
    }   
}
```

Comment: The setters should be private here to mimic the original code. I'd also change it to `Pair`, but that's a separate issue...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create your own class, .NET has supported 2 built-in classes similar this. So you can use `KeyValuePair<string, string>` or `Tuple<string, string>` instead

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has offered a fix, but nobody has answered the actual question.  The problem is that the right-hand side of your assignments is a `void` method, but it needs to have the same type as, or a type implicitly convertible to the type of, the assignment target.  Since `string` is sealed, the right hand side of the expression must, in this case, be a string expression.

```
string M1() { return "Something"; }
object M2() { return new object(); }
void M3() { }

string s = "Something"; //legal; right side's type is string
string t = M1(); //legal; right side's type is string
string u = M2(); //compiler error; right side's type is object
string v = M2().ToString(); //legal; right side's type is string
string w = (string)M2(); //compiles, but fails at runtime; right side's type is string
string x = M3(); //compiler error; right side's type is void
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the methods, just the constructor arguments:

```
public class pair
{

    private string key;
    private string value;

    public pair(string key, string value)
    {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    private string Key 
    {
        get { return key; }
        set { key = value; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that writing explicit getters and setters for trivial properties is unnecessarily verbose, since C# 3 introduced automatically implemented properties.